# Spring Security - How do I block access to any url except a few listed by role?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

So I have this web application that has three different sets of roles. One of which should allow anyone to view even if they are not logged in. Then there are a set of pages that the user must be logged into see but if they have the role of "Candidate" they cannot access. Finally, a role of "Candidate" may be able to only view their page at /candidate/ID

Basically is there a way to block access to any url basically "/**" except the links listed below? Or do I need to specify each link like /dashboard /profile

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/skillRequest/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/skillRequest/skillFormUpdate/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/password/reset").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/password/reset/complete").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/email/verify").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/view/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/embed/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", false) //Force user to always go to the home page.  
//                .successHandler(successHandler())
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what I needed I just had to add

`.antMatchers("/**").not().hasAuthority("ROLE_CANDIDATE")`

after any URL i wanted excluded from the matcher

```
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/skillRequest/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/skillRequest/skillFormUpdate/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/password/reset").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/password/reset/complete").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/email/verify").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/view/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/embed/**").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use spring security tags
for example:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/url/domestic/*" access="!hasAuthority('systemAccessRole')"/>
```

as above example use `!` and `(not)` operator.

Comment: so this means I would have to do it for every url, since "/index" would be permit all but "/**" would require a login.

Answer (score 0):

```
.antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
```

I find putting the above line as the last antmatchers works for me. It block all the API that declare on previous antMatchers

```
.antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/candidate/*").hasAuthority("ROLE_CANDIDATE")
.antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
httpSecurity.httpBasic().and().
authorizeRequests().
antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER").
antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll().
antMatchers("/**").denyAll().
and().formLogin();
```