# How to override role for a specific endpoint in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm setting up security configuration with the help of Spring Security.

I'm interested if it's possible to override a role for a more specific endpoint with the help of **HttpSecurity** object.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
httpSecurity
               .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

And I want to have another role for a more specific endpoint:

```
httpSecurity
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/specific").hasRole("ROLE_ONLY_FOR THIS_ENDPOINT")
```

Ans it doesn't work, it still requires **ADMIN** role for the specific endpoint.

Is it possible to override it somehow or exclude this endpoint from a more common role rule?

**Update 1**:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_SPECIFIC')")
    @GetMapping("/specific")
    public ResponseEntity<TopDamagedComponentsResponse> getTopDamagedComponents(
            @RequestParam(required = true) String manufacturer,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String model,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String vehicleBodyType,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String vehicleType,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "25", required = false) Integer limit){
        List<ComponentDto> topDamagedComponents = service.getTopDamagedComponents(manufacturer, model, vehicleBodyType, vehicleType, limit);
        TopDamagedComponentsFilter filter = new TopDamagedComponentsFilter(manufacturer, model, vehicleBodyType, vehicleType);
        return new ResponseEntity<TopDamagedComponentsResponse>(new TopDamagedComponentsResponse(topDamagedComponents, topDamagedComponents.size(), filter), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()


                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("ADMIN")

                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()

                .and()
                  .sessionManagement()
                      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.csrf().disable();


    }
```

I've tried to use `@PreAuthorize` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `@Secure` or `@PreAuthorize`

Comment: add the 'specific' url first , followed by the generic one

Comment: @R.G have alredy tried it and it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: @Coffemanz the order of the rules matters , the more specific rule should go first in the chain.

Comment: @Coffemanz your "/api/v1/**" configuration, includes the endpoint "/api/v1/specific" too.  (** notation)

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I inderstand this, the question is how to exclude a specific one from a general rule.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46159368/6190803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @R.G for noticing a typo. I was missing `/` in the beginning of my endpoint (`api/v1/specific`), it was like this:

```
httpSecurity
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("api/v1/specific").hasRole("ROLE_ONLY_FOR THIS_ENDPOINT")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

After adding `/` and putting rules **in the right order** in the chain (more specific ones should go first and more general ones should be in the end of the chain), it works as expected: a specific endpoint requires only a specific role and all the others under `/api/v1/**` require an admin role.

Finally it looks this way:

```
httpSecurity
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/specific").hasRole("ROLE_ONLY_FOR THIS_ENDPOINT")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('" + ROLE + "')")` above the method header.

Comment: Ok, I also added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` to my config class but it still doesn't work expected way, it still requires role ADMIN.

Comment: you added @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('"ROLE_ONLY_FOR THIS_ENDPOINT"')") right above the "/api/v1/specific" in the Controller? Please post your updated code

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question, you can check it out, thanks

Comment: web security comes before method security . the generic rule will get matched first and hence ADMIN role is required.

Comment: @R.G ok and what is the correct way to achieve what I need then? Is it possible to make an exception out of the general rule?

Comment: what exactly happens when `/api/v1/specific` is before `/api/v1/**` in your http rule chain ?. The first match in the chain will be honoured and that is how the rules should be configured , from specific to generic  .

Comment: Actually nothing happens if I put a specific one before OR after the general. It still requires the role (ADMIN) described in a general rule `(/api/v1/**)`

Comment: Just to be clear. It both cases: `.antMatchers("api/v1/specific").hasRole("SPECIFIC").antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("ADMIN")` and `.antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("api/v1/specific").hasRole("SPECIFIC")` work the same for me: it requires ADMIN role

Comment: `api/v1/specific` != `/api/v1/specific` , typo ?

Comment: Well, yes. That was an actual problem: I was missing `/` in the beginning. After adding this, it works as expected Thanks!